# Sorting arrays by frequency inside documents in MongoDB collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I'm trying to sort a couple of arrays by frequency inside every document of a MongoDB collection.

My documents right now look something like

```
{
    "_id": whatever,
    "color": "blue",
    "fruit": ["apple", "banana", "apple", "orange", "apple", "orange", ...],
    "vegetable": ["onion", "lettuce", "spinach", "lettuce", ...],
    "meat": ["pulled pork", "steak", "chicken wings", "pulled pork", "pulled pork", ...]
}
```

Note: this is not the real data but the properties of the documents are the exact same.

The end goal is to find for each color the most frequent fruit, vegetable and meat so I guessed if I could group by color and get the first element of every array ordered by frequency, that would give me what I need.

I've tried unwinding but my database is too big to unwind for every array (each one has around 50.000 elements so 50.000^3 doesn't seem ideal). I've also looked for a "mode" group function, as MongoDB has a "median" function, but it seems like there is none (v5.0.22). I've also looked at the map and the reduce function for pipelining (db.collection.aggregate({$map //or $reduce...})) but I honestly didn't get far with that since this is kind of new for me, although it seems to me that it's probable the way to go.

Has someone done something similar that might work here? Thanks!!

Comment: How can you "... find for each color the most frequent fruit, vegetable and meat"? `color` is a peer field to `fruit`.   Also:  this is mega aggregation here, not index-optimized fetch nor transactional inserts.   is running this in SPARK with data dumped into AWS S3 a possibility?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti maybe I didn't come up with the best example since, as said in the post, the data holds the properties but is not the same. For this example, imagine color is a peer field to all other properties. About the mega aggregation; yes, this is what MongoDB is supposed to do, if I was doing ACID operations I might use something else, but I need to do it on mongo.

Comment: You may have a slightly outdated  impression of what MongoDB can do.   MongoDB supports starttrans/commit/rollback across multiple docs in multiple collections -- for 8 years now in fact.   Also: the `color` field changed from being an array to single value scalar; new approach possible.   Do `fruit` etc. remain arrays 50000 long?   And how many docs overall?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti indeed, but my only business with mongo is its document orientation. About the color field, I got it wrong while copying it: its a single value that varies across documents (it wouldn't make sense otherwise, my bad). The others remain the same. The colors are not repeated since they come from a group clause. The idea is to get the mode of each of the arrays for each color but besides inserting some JS I still haven't come to a solution in native MQL

Comment: Ahhh.... so a `$group` stage already happened?  Probably with a `$push` to collect up the scalar values of `fruit` `meat` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP states that the docs we see in the question are the result of a `$group` (ostensibly on `color`) that likely `$push`es the `fruit`, `vegetable`, and `meat` values onto ever-growing arrays (as much as 50,000).  If the goal is to get the mode for each color, then `$facet` can be used as a "multigroup".  Suppose each individual docs has this shape (**NOTE**: just using `fruit` and `meat` here to simplify; the approach extends to `vegetable` and any other field in the doc):

```js
    {"color": "blue", "fruit": "A", "meat": "X"}
```

The following `$facet` pipeline will produce the modes we seek:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$facet: {
        "most_fruit": [
            // Sum by color and fruit name:                                      
            {$group: {_id: {c:'$color', v:'$fruit'}, N: {$sum: 1}}}

            // Reorg by color only....                                           
            ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.c', X:{$push: {v:'$_id.v',N:'$N'}}}}

            // ...and now sort highest-to-lowest and take the highest one.       
            // Nice thing is if you really want, you are already set up to       
            // capture, for example, the highest *nd* the lowest.                
            ,{$project: {
                X: {$first: {$sortArray: {input: '$X', sortBy: {'N':-1} }} }
            }}
        ],

        // Same thing ... but for meat                                           
        "most_meat": [
            {$group: {_id: {c:'$color', v:'$meat'}, N: {$sum: 1}}}

            ,{$group: {_id: '$_id.c', X:{$push: {v:'$_id.v',N:'$N'}}}}
            ,{$project: {
                X: {$first: {$sortArray: {input: '$X', sortBy: {'N':-1} }} }
            }}
        ]
    }}
]);
```

yields something with this shape:

```
{                                                                                
  most_fruit: [                                                                  
    {_id: 'blue', X: {v: 'A', N: 2} },                                           
    {_id: 'green',X: {v: 'F', N: 3} }                                            
  ],                                                                             
  most_meat: [                                                                   
    {_id: 'green',X: {v: 'Z', N: 4} },                                           
    {_id: 'blue', X: {x: 'X', N: 3} }                                            
  ]                                                                              
}
```

A *single* document with all information is returned.  Although it is not organized by color, there is no further processing that could be done on the database side (using MQL) to make either the grouping or filtering of data more efficient; it's now up to the client-side to set up the information.

Here is a candidate client-side reorg:

```js
var oneDoc = c.next();

function processItem(obj, fname) {
    for(var n = 0; n < obj[fname].length; n++) {
        var cn = oneDoc[fname][n]['_id'];
        if(undefined == color_major[cn]) {
            // Set up ALL the possible modes.  -1 is our way of                  
            // signalling it has not yet been set.                               
            color_major[cn] = {'most_fruit':-1,'most_meat':-1};
        }
        color_major[cn][fname] = oneDoc[fname][n]['X'];
    }
}

var color_major = {};
processItem(oneDoc, 'most_fruit');
processItem(oneDoc, 'most_meat');

print(color_major);
```

yields:

```
{
  green: { most_fruit: { v: 'F', N: 3 }, most_meat: { v: 'Z', N: 4 } },
  blue: { most_fruit: { v: 'A', N: 2 }, most_meat: { v: 'X', N: 3 } }
}
```

### If you really want to beat up the DB..

*(...but not really because the data coming of the `$facet` stage above is very small...)*

Here is the extra pipeline to reformat the data:

```js
    // Turn $facet field names (lval) into values (rval):                                         
    ,{$project: {X: {$objectToArray: '$$ROOT'} }}

    // Double unwind is OK because there is only #color X 2 (fruit and meat) entries.             
    // Even if 1000 colors and fruit meat and veg and whatevs, still quite doable:                
    ,{$unwind: '$X'}
    ,{$unwind: '$X.v'}

    // Reorg on color:                                                                            
    ,{$group: {_id: '$X.v._id', W: {$push: {k: '$X.k', v: '$X.v.X'}} }}

    // ...and put it all back together:                                                           
    ,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [ {color:'$_id'}, {$arrayToObject: '$W'} ]}
     }}
```

yields:

```js
{
  color: 'green',
  most_fruit: {
    v: 'F',
    N: 3
  },
  most_meat: {
    v: 'Z',
    N: 4
  }
}
{
  color: 'blue',
  most_fruit: {
    v: 'A',
    N: 2
  },
  most_meat: {
    v: 'X',
    N: 3
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a truly insightful and detailed explanation. I understood every step as if it was obvious (yet it wasn't for me haha). Exactly what I needed, thank you Buzz!